# Get outer html sections only using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python application using BS4 where I want to get only the outer  elements of any webpage.

For example a webpage may contain:

```
<section>
    <section>
        <section>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
```

Webpage can have as many nested section as it like but I only want to get the outermost sections which are two in this case.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: ``findall('section')``  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find_all()` with `recursive=False` parameter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<section>
    THIS IS SECTION 1 - I WANT THIS
    <section>
        THIS IS SECTION 2
        <section>
            THIS IS SECTION 3
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
<section>
    THIS IS SECTION 4 - I WANT THIS
</section>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for section in soup.find_all('section', recursive=False):
    print(section.contents[0].strip())
```

Prints:

```
THIS IS SECTION 1 - I WANT THIS
THIS IS SECTION 4 - I WANT THIS
```